# The Data is change but the father and the child cmps did not re-rendering ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, function

I want to change the amount of a product in the preview CMP that is rendered by the list CMP.
The preview changes the data and the list (father CMP) I set the updated data in the state but the cmps didn't re-rendering. the data is changed and the state is changed but the cmps are not.

**the father CMP**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { productService } from '../services/product.service.js'
import { ProductPreview } from './ProductPreview.jsx'
import { utilService } from '../services/util.service.js'

export function ProductList() {
    const [totalMoney, setTotalMoney] = useState(0)
    const [spendMoney, setSpendMoney] = useState('You havent Spent yet !')
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setTotalMoney(217000000000)
        getProducts()
    }, [])

    const getProducts = () => {

        setProducts(productService.getProducts())
    }
    
    if (products.length === 0) return <h1>loading...</h1>
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="total">
                <span> Remaining: {utilService.currencyFormat(totalMoney)}</span>
                <span>{spendMoney}</span>
            </div>
            <ul className="products-list">
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <ProductPreview
                        product={product}
                        key={product._id}
                        getProducts={getProducts}
                    />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </main>
    )


}
```

**the Previw CMP**

```
import { utilService } from '../services/util.service.js'
import { productService } from '../services/product.service.js'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
export function ProductPreview({ product, getProducts }) {
    const [currProduct, setCurrProduct] = useState(product)

    const changeAmount = (diff) => {
        const newProduct = productService.increasAmount(currProduct._id, diff)
        
        setCurrProduct(newProduct)
        getProducts()
        
    }
    return (
        <li className="product-preview">
            <img src={currProduct.img} alt="" />
            <h1>{currProduct.name}</h1>
            <h1>{utilService.currencyFormat(currProduct.price)}</h1>
            <div className="actions">
                <button onClick={() => changeAmount(-1)} className="sell">
                    Sell
                </button>
                <p>{currProduct.amount}</p>
                <button onClick={() => changeAmount(1)} className="buy">
                    Buy
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: My guess would be This is because currProduct is set only once and component won't re-render when product props changes. Try useEffect and update currProduct when product props changes.

Comment: If increaseAmount is an async operation you need to await that operation to finish before fetching the products again. Otherwise, you could fetch stale products.

Comment: the return data is right and the cmp get the that data but dont re-render

Comment: Please, show us the `productService.getProducts()` method, my guess that it does not rerender due to productService operates an array that is its field, your `setProducts` detects that a reference to array is the same (even with updated data) and does not call for a rerender

Comment: function getProducts() {
 // console.log(products)
 return products
}

Comment: The getProducts function gets you the array of the products the is require by the service